# DolphinDB: the “extra” and “comment” columns in the output table colDefs of schema

Tags: datatable, schema, dolphindb

Using the function `schema`, I got a set of information including the following *colDefs* table.

[image]

Within the table, I noticed two additional columns: “extra” and “comment”. Can anyone explain what they are used for? Furthermore, if I want to insert values to these columns, which function should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- extra: displays the scale of the decimal number for columns of type
  DECIMAL
- comment: provides additional details about a specific column

To add a comment to a specific column, you can use `setColumnComment`.

For the “extra” column, data is automatically inserted in the case of a column of type DECIMAL.